# Filtering on custom fields in apostrophe-headless

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am using apostrophe with apostrophe-headless. I have an apostrophe-pieces module called bundles, which I would like to filter based on a custom field. The documentation and it says that I need to define an apostrophe-pieces-pages module in order to enable that.

This is my configuration:

```
  'bundles': {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name: 'bundles',
    restApi: {
      maxPerPage: 10,
    }
  },

  'bundles-pages': {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
    piecesFilters: [
      {
        name: 'name'
      },
      {
        name: 'slug'
      }
    ]
  },
```

If I do full text search:

```
/api/v1/bundles?page=1&search=text
```

it works as expected, but if I try to filter on the slug:

```
/api/v1/bundles?page=1&slug=slug_value
```

it returns all bundles instead of the matching one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apostrophe-pieces-pages` are not required to make cursor filter methods available to the API and other code. I think that confusion comes from the fact that the documentation focuses on `apostrophe-pieces-pages` because rendering full pages directly is the use case the main series of Apostrophe tutorials focuses on.

With help from you, we have updated `apostrophe-headless` to support an option to specify filters that should be marked "safe" for the public API in the same way that apostrophe-pieces-pages does it:

```
'my-module': {
  restApi: {
    // We're assuming here that you have added fields
    // called 'color' and 'brand' in your schema
    safeFilters: [ 'slug', 'color', 'brand' ]
  }
}
```

However, for anyone keen to query on the slug property in particular, keep in mind that if you're making API calls you are probably better off fetching things by their `_id`, using the documented REST pattern:

`/api/v1/bundles/IDGOESHERE`

Slugs, unlike the _id, are subject to occasional change. If you know the _id and you're not creating a user-facing "friendly URL" then you should use the _id.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Tom. I am actually trying to do a filter based on custom fields in there, not just the slug field. I have a name, version, category fields that I'd like to search on. Will that PR allow me to do that too?

Comment: This turns out to be more of an apostrophe-headless issue. apostrophe-pieces-pages is calling safeFilters, apostrophe-headless should introduce an easy way to do that for your API-enabled pieces modules too. https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless/issues/14#issuecomment-379744190

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem and found the solution was to add a custom filter as documented here: https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html#custom-filters

The only change I made to the sample code shown in that link is on the line starting with self.and({... The problem is that when no documents match the specific slug, then the and still returns the initial cursor which contains all the documents but really you need it to return nothing. So, instead of :

self.and({ marketId: market._id });

I did this (bit hacky, but you get the idea):

self.and({ marketId: market === undefined ? 9999999999 : market._id });